# how to solve header location warning wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Hi I want to create a simple login code to redirect each user to his own profile page.

I'm using a page "CleanPage" as a template for my php code.

I tried `header Location` and  `wp_redirect` but both shows this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/general-template.php:1076) in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/sydney/CleanPage.php on line 43

I wanted simple redirection like this:

```
header("Location: auth_customer.php?id=$userid");
```

Any help please?

Comment: try this: `header("Location: auth_customer.php?id=" . $userid);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: you have to expand on your answer as to where exactly are you using this piece of code

Comment: @RonnieOosting also it shows the same problem (actually my code works well without wordpress, problems started when I switched to wp)

Comment: @kenzotenma I have edited my post: I'm writing my code in a php page inside the theme (template)

Comment: try `header("Location: 'FULL_PATH'/auth_customer.php?id=" . $userid);`

Comment: @RonnieOosting I don't think this will ever work. she's trying to send header information alongside the main content. any kind of header information has to be sent before sending the main response.

Comment: you should give this a read: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers -- this may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest one is to use 'meta refresh', try like this `<?php echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=auth_customer.php?id=$userid'>"; ?>`.

Comment: this actually works well, but I'm not sure if I can still conserve sessions with this

Comment: It's just equivalent of PHP `header()` so anything work with it will work with this too.

Answer (score 3):

though I've already posted the link in the comment section above. I believe this should definitely solve your problem

```
<?php
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_header_xua' );
function add_header_xua() {
    // your login logic or whatever should go here
    // ....
    header("Location: auth_customer.php?id=$userid");
}
```

Comment: also this code still give me the same warning :( I used it in my CleanPage.php, should I write it on functions.php?

Comment: I can see the logic: it's as u said, sending my custom header before calling that 'wp_head();'  but even this didn't work :((
maybe it's my bad that I didn't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Add an action to "wp_loaded" with a custom function and then make redirect within it.

```
<?php
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'ss_custom_redirect');
function ss_custom_redirect() {
    $redirect = 'http://example.com/redirect-example-url.html';
    wp_redirect($redirect);
    exit;
}     
?>
```

Comment: I still get that worning: 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/general-template.php:1076) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wp_redirect( home_url('/auth_customer.php?id='.$userid) ); exit;
```

Comment: still the same warning and it's because I'm forcing wp to overwrite the header ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the redirect function before get_header() / wp_head() 
for example:

```
if( //some logic here ) { 
  wp_redirect('page1');
} else {
  wp_redirect('page2');
}
...
get_header();
```

Comment: There must be something is sent / printed from the server before the redirect, maybe happens before calling the custom template.